# Speed up Mysql Query using a split function

Tags: mysql, sql, split

I am trying to speed up a MYSQL query. 
In a column called "MISC", I first have to extract a "traceID" variable, that will be used to match row of another table.
Example of the MISC column:

```
PFFCC_Strip/fkk49322/PMethod=Diners/CardType=Diners/9999******9999/2010/TraceId=7122910
```

I am extracting the value "7122910" as traceID and find corresponding row with a left join. The traceId value being unique, only one row must be present on each table.

I cannot set Index on the tables to speed up process. Any approach that could make this query run faster? As it is, it takes a few seconds to run which is not possible.

```
select *
from
(select TraceID,PP,UDef2, Payment_Method, Approved, TransactionID, Amount
from pr) pr
left join 
(select 
 PAYMENT_ID as Payment_ID_omega, TRANSACTION_TYPE, 
 REQUESTED_AMOUNT, AMOUNT, `STATUS` as StatusRef_omega,
 REQUEST_DATE, Agent,
 if (locate('TraceId=',MISC)>0, SUBSTRING_INDEX(MISC,'TraceId=',-1),'') as traceID
from BankingActivity ) omega
on pr.TraceID = omega.traceID
having
(REQUEST_DATE BETWEEN DATE_ADD(DATE(NOW()), INTERVAL -1 DAY) AND NOW())
ORDER BY pr.TraceID DESC
```

Comment: correct, thanks for observation, duly edited and corrected.

Answer (score 0):

You can place your filters inside the query before join that must make a difference and you must have the index on table pr(TraceID) and BankingActivity(REQUEST_DATE, traceID). For more optimised query, Please post the execution plan.

```
select * from(select TraceID
                    ,PP
                    ,UDef2
                    ,Payment_Method
                    ,Approved
                    ,TransactionID
                    ,Amount
               from pr) pr
left join (select PAYMENT_ID as Payment_ID_omega
                 ,TRANSACTION_TYPE
                 ,REQUESTED_AMOUNT
                 ,AMOUNT
                 ,`STATUS` as StatusRef_omega
                 ,REQUEST_DATE
                 ,Agent
                 ,if (locate('TraceId=', MISC) > 0, SUBSTRING_INDEX(MISC,'TraceId=',-1),'') as traceID 
           from BankingActivity
           WHERE REQUEST_DATE BETWEEN DATE_ADD(DATE(NOW()), INTERVAL -1 DAY) AND NOW()) omega
on pr.TraceID = omega.traceID
ORDER BY pr.TraceID DESC
```

Comment: Thanks, the query is now down from 7.6 sec to 7.3 sec. I was expecting a better speed though

Comment: Add a stored Virtual Column that extract the id a set a index on it. This field will automatic filled if you change the misc field